# Find the 28th derivative of $f(x) = x^3 \sin(x^2)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to do this problem using the Maclaurin series of sine but I get that the exponent on $x$ is $4n+5$. Therefore, there is no integer value for which $28 = 4n+5$. Does this imply $c_{28}=0$ and hence the derivative is zero as well?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you wanted to calculate $f^{(28)}(0)$ and not $f^{(28)}(x)$ for arbitrary real $x$.

If so, then your reasoning is correct. Even simpler, note that $f(x) = x^3\sin(x^2)$ is an odd function, and thus, $f^{(2k)}(0) = 0$ for any non-negative integer $k$.